# Using Asp.Net Core Identity in MVC, Authorize attribute is rebouncing to login page after succesfull login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, identity, authorize

After long googling nights, asking my question here is the last drastic attempt to solve the problem. I'm reading a book of Adam Freeman, called Pro Asp.Net Core Mvc 2. I reached a very interesting chapter where the author creates a user login/register system using Identity API. The example is really simple but I've got stucked, and as I haven't seen any post using this approach, I decided to create a question here. So in the book, here is the user model class inherited from IdentityUser:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace supafood.Models
{
public class AppUser:IdentityUser
{
    //basic identity instalation

}
    }
```

And then here is an addition userviewmodel class, model passed to the login form

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace supafood.Models
{
    public class CreateModel
    {
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    }

    public class LoginModel
    {
        [Required]
        [UIHint("email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [UIHint("password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public string returnUrl { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller of the starting page, redirect unauthorized users to login page

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

namespace supafood.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController:Controller
    {
    [Authorize]
    public ViewResult Index() =>
        View(new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            ["Placeholder"] = "Placeholder"
        });
    }
}
```

Login View page:

```
@model LoginModel

<div class="bg-primary mm-1 p-1 text-white"><h4>Log in</h4></div>

<div class="text-danger" asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
<h3>@ViewBag.returnUrl</h3> 
<p>@ViewData["mess"]</p> 

<form asp-action="Login" method="post">

<input type="hidden" asp-for="returnUrl" value="@ViewBag.returnUrl" />

<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Email"></label>
    <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Password"></label>
    <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Login</button>
</form>
```

And the AccountController handling the login attempt, returning the redirect to the requested page.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using supafood.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace supafood.Controllers
{

[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{

    private UserManager<AppUser> userMan;
    private SignInManager<AppUser> signinMan;

    public AccountController(UserManager<AppUser> UserM, 
  SignInManager<AppUser> SignM)
    {
        userMan = UserM;
        signinMan = SignM;
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {

        ViewBag.returnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel details)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            AppUser user =await  userMan.FindByEmailAsync(details.Email);
            ViewData["name"] = user.UserName;
            if (user != null)
            {
                await signinMan.SignOutAsync();
                Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInResult result = await 
signinMan.PasswordSignInAsync(user, details.Password, false, false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {


                    return Redirect(details.returnUrl);
                }

            }
            ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(LoginModel.Email), "Invalid user         
or password");
        }
        return View(details);

    }
}
}
```

StartUp Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using supafood.Models;
using supafood.Infrastructure;


namespace supafood
{
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<IPasswordValidator<AppUser>, 
CustomPasswordValidator>();

        services.AddDbContext<AppIdentityDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration["Data:SupafoodConnection:ConnectionString"]));

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(opts => opts.LoginPath = 
"/Users/Login");

        services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>(opts =>
        {
            opts.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            opts.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            opts.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            opts.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            opts.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            opts.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            opts.Password.RequireDigit = false;
        }
        )
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure 
the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseStatusCodePages();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        routes.MapRoute("default", " 
{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"));
        app.UseAuthentication();
    }
}
}
```

The problem is, that after login, the authorize attribute is rebouncing  "the user" to the login page. I read some posts regarding some custom cookie setting options and IPrincipal implementation in order to fix this issue. The question is how is possible, that it worked for the author with no additional customization.
My knowledge is still basic so I'm trying to keep it simple for now, until I understand the core concepts.
Every help is appreciated.
Thanks, Zsolt.

Comment: Did you reach to `signinMan.PasswordSignInAsync` when you debug?

Comment: Can you share your startup.cs file code for authorization setup?

Comment: Moshin, I've added the startup class to the post.Thanks. Password singinasync is called.It seems that the result is succeded but for some reason the authorize attribute is re-redirecting me to the login page.

Comment: @domjanzsoo try moving the `app.UseAuthentication()` above `app.UseMvc()`. The order in which middleware is registered matters.

Comment: Matt, you're the man. The problem was that the app.UseMvc function was first. I'd never figured this small thing by myself. Thank you a lot. I can carry on with my reading. Thanks. I think I cannot mark the answer right unless you add some code to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of middleware registration matters. Move the `app.UseAuthentication()` call to before `app.UseMvc(...)`.

Typically, anything that happens *before* a response is returned (like authentication) should come before the MVC middleware is registered.